# npm install error: 'ENOENT: no such file or directory'

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, package.json, npm-scripts

I donwload a project form somewhere , and I run 'npm install' , I got this:

```
npm ERR! path /Users/<username>/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/<username>/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

but I have checked the project , there were a package.json file there:
`/Users/username/Desktop/Directory/Projects/ProjectName/package.json`

do I need to use `npm init` to create another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cd to the directory where package.json is (`/Users/username/Desktop/Directory/Projects/ProjectName/` in your case) and run `npm install` again.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplest solution:

Simply run `npm init` and it will walk you through the process of **creating** `package.json` file