# New to React i am facing this start error in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, router

Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Install the latest PowerShell for new features and improvements! https://aka.ms/PSWindows

```
PS D:\React> cd textutils
PS D:\React\textutils> npm start
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\React\textutils/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React\textutils\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rohan Singla\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-09T05_03_35_157Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\React\textutils> npm start
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\React\textutils/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React\textutils\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rohan Singla\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-09T05_04_02_318Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\React\textutils> npm start
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\React\textutils/package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\React\textutils\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Rohan Singla\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-09T05_10_17_763Z-debug-0.log
PS D:\React\textutils>
```

Comment: Does your PC username have a space in it, i.e. "Rohan Singla" ?

Comment: Have you checked these two threads: [npm install error: 'ENOENT: no such file or directory'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56230767/npm-install-error-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory) and [npm install errors with Error: ENOENT, chmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990647/npm-install-errors-with-error-enoent-chmod)
You may find your solution in these.

Answer (score 0):

Open your C:\Program Files\nodejs

you need to change one thing in your 4 files i.e.
open your npm, npm.cmd, npx, npx.cmd and edit prefix -g with prefix --location=global.
and save it as administration.
Do this